# Red dot under Neutral symbol on 2012 Dodge Caravan

Tags: dodge, indicators, caravan

I've noticed there is a red circle showing up underneath my "N" on the dash.

Dot is not flashing and has remained on for last couple of days.

Can't figure out what it is from Google/manual.   Any ideas?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: My 2012 Grand caravan is doing the vary same thing. Did you ever figure this out? Have no clue what's going on but it won't start. :-/

Answer (score 6):

I found a copy of the owner's manual [here](http://www.dodge.com/download/pdf/manuals/2012-Grand_Caravan-OM-3rd.pdf).  Pages 284-285 have a diagram of the instrument cluster, where this light appears as #17.  Page 294 says that this is the **Vehicle Security Light** and explains:

> This light will flash at a fast rate for approximately 15 seconds, when the vehicle security alarm is arming, and then will flash slowly
>   until the vehicle is disarmed.

Comment: It's solid, not flashing at all and has remained on for two days

Comment: I don't know why that would happen, but hopefully this at least helps you narrow down what to look for.  Possibly a problem with the security system?

Comment: Since it is solid, I'd think this could either indicate a problem with the security system, or it needs to be reset. Most security systems will reset if you get out of the vehicle with all the doors closed, then lock/unlock using one of your master keys (not the key fob). I don't know if this will work in this situation, but it's worth a try.